# Unity: This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement error even after unchecked x86 in player setings

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, google-play

I'm trying to deploy my android application into Google play store but I'm continuously getting the following error even after unchecking x86 build according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561855/apks-or-app-bundles-are-available-to-64-bit-devices-but-they-only-have-32-bit-na) question and recreating the `.apk` and uploading to the Google Play Console.
[image]

My player settings are,
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from August 2019 the Google Play store requires any new application to be native 64 bit. Currently you are building your apk in 32-bits instead of 64-bits.

From the [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit):

> Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need to support 64-bit architectures. 64-bit CPUs deliver faster, richer experiences for your users. Adding a 64-bit version of your app provides performance improvements, makes way for future innovation, and sets you up for devices with 64-bit-only hardware.

ARMv7 is a 32-bit architecture, from the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidArchitecture.ARMv7.html):

> 32-bit ARM architecture.
>   Corresponds to armeabi-v7a ABI.

You need to use the ARM64 option that you can use after enabling IL2CPP, from the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidArchitecture.ARM64.html):

> 64-bit ARM architecture.
>   Corresponds to arm64-v8a ABI.

The x86 option you unchecked is also a 32 bit architecture, but just a different 32 bit architecture (intel's), from the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidArchitecture.X86.html):

> 32-bit Intel architecture.
>   Corresponds to x86 ABI.

Comment: Thank you for your time, After enabling IL2CPP unity is asking for NDK path please can you explain me to how to address this matter

Comment: @IndrajithEkanayake under Edit > preferences> External Tools there is a section "Android". Here you find the "Android NDK" version. depending on your Unity version it will have a checkbox saying "Android NDK installed with Unity (Recommended). If that option is there check it, if it still doesn't work you can manually download an NDK from Android here https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases (Newer NDK's may give problem, I personally always use NDK r16b as it seems most stable..) After downloading the NDK you just have to set the path to where you installed it

Answer (score 2):

You need to create `App Bundle` using `IL2CPP` (`ARM64` should be enabled when `IL2CPP` selected).
For more detailed information you should check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html) document.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps that fix this issue if you have android studio.

0. Download the recommended android api on android studio and copy the sdk location.
1. Go to Edit->Prefrences window in unity. And choose the External Tools tab.
2. Delete the default location of android sdk and past the sdk location which you copied in step zero.