# xamarin: 64bit warning in google play

Tags: android, xamarin, 64-bit

Warning
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 5.

From 1 February 2020 all releases must be compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code that it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More

[image]

[image]

[image]

I received this warning when uploading to google playStore. Does that mean i still have something not configure to support 64 bit in my apk.

When i typed this command:

```
zipinfo -1 com.aimyplus.provider.apk | grep \.so$
lib/arm64-v8a/libmonodroid.so
lib/arm64-v8a/libxamarin-app.so
lib/arm64-v8a/libmonosgen-2.0.so
lib/arm64-v8a/libmono-btls-shared.so
lib/x86/libmonodroid.so
lib/x86/libxamarin-app.so
lib/x86/libmonosgen-2.0.so
lib/x86/libmono-btls-shared.so
lib/x86_64/libmonodroid.so
lib/x86_64/libxamarin-app.so
lib/x86_64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
lib/x86_64/libmono-btls-shared.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libmonodroid.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libxamarin-app.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libmonosgen-2.0.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libmono-btls-shared.so
lib/arm64-v8a/libe_sqlite3.so
lib/arm64-v8a/libmono-native.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libe_sqlite3.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libmono-native.so
lib/x86/libe_sqlite3.so
lib/x86_64/libe_sqlite3.so
lib/x86/libmono-native.so
lib/x86_64/libmono-native.so
```

Comment: Perhaps you are using a JNI C/C++ library in your app. Check using Android Studio tools: https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/64-bit?hl=en

Comment: how do i checked cause i am running using xamarin studio. I used command and check the .so and all files generated.

Comment: @LittleFunny Your Release configuration is showing no ABIs selected?

Comment: It was all ticked in the image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348216/how-to-find-if-apk-is-32-bit-or-64-bit comment by  StenSoft  that i can ignore it, it said he didn't have any app but still received this message. Is this true?

Comment: I can see abi-apk have 4 different apk file related to the image above. Is it because I deploy an apk with all architecture in it to play store so that is why that warning message pop up but my app already supportrd

Comment: @LittleFunny The "all ticked" image is the "Debug" config, the "Release" shows nothing selected?

Comment: @sushiHangover i actually noticed if i choose the release config in menu bar and open the dialog. It will show as release and ticked as the Debug in second photo. Once I selected other ui e.g.changing to debug, the setting back to grey out and back to release config it will back to third photo. So does that mean there are 3 representation in those checkboxex. Ticked, ticked but grey out and not checked

Comment: @LittleFunny, find one same thread, you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026974/xamarin-this-release-is-not-compliant-with-the-google-play-64-bit-requirement