# Build app Xamarin.Android with visual studio 2022 get an error "not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement"

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I have an application written in Xamarin.Adnroid, I build with Visual studio 2022 Target Framework and Target android version is Android 12.0(S). In the Support architecture section I tried selecting both armeabi-7a; x86; x86_64 and arm64 but when I update to Google store, I get an error as shown. If anyone has encountered this situation before, please give me some suggestions. Thanks

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
<DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>portable</DebugType>
<Optimize>True</Optimize>
<OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<AndroidManagedSymbols>true</AndroidManagedSymbols>
<AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
<AndroidLinkMode>SdkOnly</AndroidLinkMode>
<EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
<AotAssemblies>false</AotAssemblies>
<EnableLLVM>false</EnableLLVM>
<AndroidEnableProfiledAot>false</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
<BundleAssemblies>false</BundleAssemblies>
<AndroidEnableMultiDex>true</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
<AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>true</AndroidEnableSGenConcurrent>
<MandroidI18n />
<AndroidSupportedAbis Condition=" '$(AndroidSupportedAbis)' == '' ">armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
<AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
<AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>
<AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>false</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
<AndroidKeyStore>false</AndroidKeyStore>

<AndroidDexTool>dx</AndroidDexTool>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSVsz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpbau.png)
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [5]
Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems that all the steps is right, have you tried to rebuild and re-upload the project? In addition, you can check the [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026974/xamarin-this-release-is-not-compliant-with-the-google-play-64-bit-requirement).

Comment: thank you Liyun Zhang. I have updated successfully, because while creating a new release I did not delete the old version code