# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I'm trying to upload an old xamarin android app to the playstore I'm getting this error

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
> they only have 32-bit native code: [7, 18] Include 64-bit and 32-bit
> native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format
> to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only
> the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of
> your app. Learn More

I tried different methods and suggestions. but nothing works
also tried below StackOverflow suggestion but result is the same
[APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices but they only have 32-bit native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561855/apks-or-app-bundles-are-available-to-64-bit-devices-but-they-only-have-32-bit-na)

This is my project file for the release build properties.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <EnableProguard>true</EnableProguard>
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize></JavaMaximumHeapSize>
       <AndroidLinkSkip>Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat;Xamarin.Android.Support.v4</AndroidLinkSkip>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    <AndroidLinkTool>r8</AndroidLinkTool>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm using some old packages due to compatibility issues. Is that making issue here ?

Apart from this I'm getting few warnings from Playstore.

- Some users of this APK may not be able to upgrade to the new APK added in this release.
- This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users. Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users' devices.
- There is no deobfuscation file associated with this APK. If you use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will make crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug. Using R8/proguard can help reduce app size.
- This APK contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug.
- There is no deobfuscation file associated with this APK. If you use obfuscated code (R8/proguard), uploading a deobfuscation file will make crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug. Using R8/proguard can help reduce app size.
- This APK contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug

Comment: Did you checked armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a? Make sure thease two only checked

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/messages/xa0115.md

Comment: There are several things you'll need to do since App Bundles are required for all Android app submissions now. Update all the support libraries to AndroidX instead of the old support libraries, the target android API has to be set to at least 30 (Android 11), and then an App Bundle must be made for upload. For more info check out this [Google blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/new-android-app-bundle-and-target-api.html#:~:text=In%202021%2C%20we%20are%20continuing,Android%20App%20Bundle%20publishing%20format.)

Comment: @NickPeppers looks like I'm not making App Bundles. But I set target libraries to API level 30. When checking the App bundles option in visual studio for mac, I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Anand both armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a are present in the release options

Comment: @NickPeppers I tried with app bundles, but it still, shows the same error in playstore.

Comment: There is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989086/build-app-xamarin-android-with-visual-studio-2022-get-an-error-not-compliant-wi) on the SO, you can check it.

Comment: Try to clean the project (and even delete bin and obj folders manually). You can try with the empty project and code you presented above and see that it works, so there is no need to ask for something that works, you need to provide more details if those instructions don't resolve the problem.